# How to select file from local storage? Ionic File Picker Error

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have installed filePicker plugin for ios, and I used it to pick a file and upload it to the server.

```html
this.filePicker.pickFile()
.then(uri => {
    var mimeType = '';
    var pathUrl = '';
    var type = '';

    (<any>window).FilePath.resolveNativePath(uri)
        .then(filePath => {
            pathUrl = filePath;
        });

    (<any>window).resolveLocalFileSystemURL(uri, (entry) => {
        entry.file(file => {
                // loading.dismiss();
                this.upload_file_path.push({mimeType: file.type, filePath: pathUrl});
                this.upload_file_name.push(pathUrl.substr(pathUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
                this.chRef.detectChanges();
            }, ((error) => {}));
    });
    this.upload_file.push(uri);
})
.catch(err => {
    this.global.presentAlert("Error!", 'Cannot add attachment');
});
```

But the code is always giving me the following error
undefined is not an object (evaluating `window.filepath.resolvenativepath`).

Answer (score 0):

Filepath plugin wasn't installed properly. Remove the plugin and install it.

`cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-filepath`

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-filepath`

Cordova Filepath : https://github.com/hiddentao/cordova-plugin-filepath